# What are the possible values for the duplicaterecords attribute in armx files

Tags: remedy

I'm looking to automate an import to remedy ARS 8.1, and I'm 99.9999% there... I just need to change what the import does with duplicate records, as everything else seems to be working exactly as desired.

In remedy armx files (mapping file for the dataimporttool), there is a `<datahandling>` node with a `duplicaterecords` attribute, [the only documentation I can find on it](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ars81/Importing+in+a+multithreaded+environment?src=search&src=search) mentions the value `GEN_NEW_ID`, which would logically map to the "Generate New ID for Duplicate Records" option in the GUI import tool. I need the value to logically map to the "Update Old Record with New Record's Data" GUI option (both of these options and the other three possible options are described on the [Defining Data Import preferences](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ars81/Defining+Data+Import+preferences) page in BMC docs.

Other than that one page (Importing in...), and the several local versions of the exact same paragraph in all the remedy documentation I have, Google turns up nothing. Please tell me someone has this information somewhere!

Comment: have you tried setting the option in data import tool and saving the armx file, and then looking at the file gain?

Comment: @josste - I don't think so. File gain? Look at it again? I haven't personally used the gui import tool, only the .bat script. I don't have a copy of the import tool on my workstation, but I can get that tried. Looking over a shoulder, I only remember seeing an "arx"file, unless I somehow missed the "m" - and that was in the context of opening the mapping for consumption by the import tool. I'll have a close look on Monday.

Comment: If you'd like I can do a test but since I am on vacation it depends on whether I have a virtual machine with ars on my personal computer

Comment: @josste I'd love to have a verification, if you're able. I can't test myself until Monday, though.

Comment: I'll take a peak at it monday morning. I think i have a VM lying around with all the tools installed...

Comment: @josste - that gave me the one value I'm looking for. I'll give you some time if you wanna answer for the question (possible values), or else I'll put it up as an answer myself at some point. Thanks for the idea of where to look. seems pretty shabby I'd have to generate several mapping files to get the possible values... c'est la (qui est) Remède!

Comment: ceci, c'est une resultat! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saving .armx files from the GUI, I have found the following options and values for the `duplicaterecords` attribute in the `<datahandling>` tag.

```
Title                                      Value in .armx file
Generate New ID for All Records            GEN_NEW_ID
Reject Duplicate Records                   DUP_ERROR
Generate New ID for Duplicate Records      DUP_NEW_ID
Replace Old Record with New Record         DUP_OVERWRITE
Update Old Record with New Record's Data   DUP_MERGE
```

Comment: Am I completely unreasonable in thinking that BMC should have that in a public document somewhere? THANKS!!!

Comment: I would personally have no idea where to start looking in the Javadoc, considering that it is an XML attribute in a file that is referenced by a batch file and then passed into a Java assembly. That seems like its expression level of abstraction to give it a different name at the very least, though the value that I did have  would probably have persisted

Comment: Historically a lot of those values had to be looked up in header files (c code)  which is not very user friendly. Since bmc has started keeping their documentation online I have been commenting on it to improve it, so that it becomes more usable. I'll probably do the same for this.